# Is selling a put a wash sale if the buyer does not exercise within 30 days of purchasing the put?

Tags: stocks, wash-sale

Let's say you sell an equity on the 1st of the month for a loss.  On the 10th of the month, you sell a put on the same equity.

If the put is not exercised by the counterparty of the put within 30 days, is it still a wash sale?

(I'm assuming that if they buyer of the put exercises within 30 days, it's a wash sale... right?)

Answer (score 0):

If you buy (or sell) a substantially identical security after realizing a loss, it's a wash sale.  It doesn't matter what happens subsequently to your option (assignment, exercise or expiry).  It is or it isn't.

If it is a wash sale, it's not a problem if all involved positions are closed by the end of the year.  It becomes an accounting issue  if a wash sale is carried over into the new tax year.

The real question is, is it a wash sale?  That's where the answer gets murky.

From [Fairmark.com](https://fairmark.com/investment-taxation/capital-gain/wash/wash-sales-and-options/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20turn%20a%20sale%20of%20stock,in%20the%20money%20for%20the%20rule%20to%20apply.):

> Selling Put Options

> You can also turn a sale of stock into a wash sale by selling put options. This rule is not automatic. It applies only if the put option is deep in the money — and there’s no precise standard as to when a put option is deep enough in the money for the rule to apply. The rule applies if it appears, at the time you sell the put option, that there is no substantial likelihood it will expire unexercised. In this circumstance, selling the put option can be roughly equivalent to buying the stock.

And from the [NASDAQ](https://www.nasdaq.com/articles/strategies-help-clients-around-wash-sale-rule-2015-11-10):

> SELL STOCK, SELL PUT

> Lastly, clients can sell their stock for a loss and then sell a put option on those shares.

> Example: Mary buys XYZ stock at $50; it is now at $35. Mary sells at $35, realizing a $15 loss. Mary then sells a 31-day put, allowing the buyer to put that stock back to Mary at $40 a share. If the stock stays below $40, Mary gets her shares back. Is this a wash sale?

> In a put sale, the government will declare a wash sale when the put position is substantially identical to the stock – that is, when there is a high likelihood that the put will be exercised (unlike the call purchase rule that damns any call purchase).

> Most tax practitioners would have no issue if Mary sells an out-of-the-money put, a slight caution if Mary sells an at-the-money put and a genuine concern if the put is in-the-money, with concern growing as the put gets deeper and deeper in the money.

Comment: You wrote "it's not a problem", but don't you lose the ability to write-off the entire loss of the wash sale?  Also, what do you mean by "it's an accounting issue" when the sale is one year and the exercise is the next year?

Comment: If I sell 100 shares and realize a loss on Dec 15th and buy the 100 shares back on Dec 16th, it's a wash sale. The loss on the first shares must be carried forward until the 2nd 100 shares are sold. Nothing lost, just deferred (an accounting issue). If I sell  the new shares by Dec 31st, I get to claim the original loss this year as well as the new shares gain or loss. If  I do not sell the new shares by Dec 31st, the loss is carried forward and the new shares have an adjusted cost basis.  A monster of an accounting headache is buy 1,000, sell 200 at a loss, buy 300, sell 400, etc.

Comment: So if you sell the put this year (on an equity you just sold for a loss), and then the counterparty to the put exercises within 30 days, but that exercise date is *next* year, then do you claim the loss of the original equity sale for *this* year even though it's a wash sale?

Comment: Per the explanations in my answer, when you sell the short put, if it's a wash sale (deep ITM put), the realized loss on the stock is deferred until next year if the short put is not closed this year.  If you sell a qualified short put (OTM) and you are assigned this year (within 30 days of realizing the stock loss), then the realized loss on the first stock position is deferred until next year if new shares are not closed this year.

Comment: So conversely, sell equity on the 10th of December for a loss.  Sell a *barely* OTM put this year on December 29th, and it's not exercised by the put's counterparty until the 2nd of January, then the ***full*** original equity loss is for ***this*** year?  Is that correct?  Then next year, the cost-basis of the purchase forced by the put has to be adjusted, but that only potentially affects next year's taxes, and not this year's taxes.

Comment: If there's no wash sale this year then you get to deduct the loss on the stock this year.  The short put is now a standalone entity, there is no adjustment to it and the realized loss on the stock is of no consequence to it.  The cost basis of the assigned shares from the assignment of the short put would be the strike price less the net premium received and the future gain or loss on those shares would be be accounted for in the tax return for the year in which you sell those shares.

Comment: Why would the put now be a standalone entity?  If the original equity sale for a loss was December 10, and the put contract was established on December 29, and the buyer of the put exercises on January 2, isn't that still a wash sale that needs special accounting?

Comment: Standalone was incorrect description. Sorry about that.  If the sale of the short put doesn't trigger a wash sale, then it's not a tax issue as long as you aren't assigned within 30 days of the realized loss.  If assigned on Jan 2nd and within 30 days of the initial realized stock loss then you have a wash sale and it requires loss deferral (loss carried forward until next year).